# What is the aim of $$PLSQL_UNIT in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I ahve question that I see many times in one package body different procedure used $$PLSQL_UNIT and I do not understand what is the aim of this. If it returns package or procedure name then we can replace with CONSTANT.

I want to aim of using that

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS002) says:

> $$PLSQL_UNIT: A VARCHAR2 literal that contains the name of the current PL/SQL unit. If the current PL/SQL unit is an anonymous block, then $$PLSQL_UNIT contains a NULL value.

Can you replace it with a constant? Sure you can, if you want.

---

Basically, it is about *conditional compilation* which

> lets you customize the functionality of a PL/SQL application without removing source text. For example, you can:
>
> - Use new features with the latest database release and disable them when running the application in an older database release.
> - Activate debugging or tracing statements in the development environment and hide them when running the application at a production site.

$$PLSQL_UNIT is part of *predefined inquiry directives*.

So - have a look at that document ([conditional compilation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS00210) is here).